# Раздать гномам шарики

Tags: алгоритм

Гномики решили встречать гостей с разноцветными шарами. Раздай шарики гномикам так, чтобы цвет шарика не был такой же, как цвет колпачка, и чтобы у гномиков в одинаковых по цвету колпачках были шарики разного цвета и разной формы. Рассмотрите все возможные варианты.

---

Пожалуйста, помогите разработать алгоритм для решения этой задачи. Можно примеры на C++, C#, Delphi. Заранее спасибо. Очень надеюсь услышать ваши идеи/советы

Comment: Шарики разной _формы_? Ну и ну!

А по сути: непонятно, что задано заранее, а что нужно определить. Количество гномиков/шариков/цветов?

Comment: http://ovrload.ru/f/39976_ans_mat_1-1.doc тут есть пример. Страница 6.

Comment: Вообще-то, по правилам, нельзя решать полностью за человека задачу, надо показывать, что имеется и что именно не получается.

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что работа за автора

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Задайте цвета и форму - числами. 
У вас будет массив гномов - массив чисел (vector<int>), указывающих на цвет колпачка гнома, и массив шариков, каждый элемент которого состоит из двух чисел - цвет и форма (vector<pair<int, int> >).

Я так понимаю, они задаются пользователем.

И тогда бизнес-логика сводится к тому, чтобы сформировать массив пар значений - индекс из массива гномов и индекс из массива шаров - vector<pair<int, int>> - все возможные количество раз.

Если нет требований к производительности, чтобы не выдумывать сложную логику, я бы сформировал сначала вообще все возможные варианты (тот самый "Цэ из Эн по Ка"), а потом выбросил не подходящие под условие варианты.